# Why browser accepts lose html syntax?

Tags: html, browser

Below `meta` tag syntax is accepted by the browser,

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; redirect.html"/>
```

but, *https://validator.w3.org* could accept below syntax(only),

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=redirect.html"/>
```

So,

1) Why browser accepts lose syntax of html?

2) For production code, what is the standard approach to validate html syntax?

Comment: For your point 2: if it validates against w3 it should be displayed (almost) identical in all browsers. If it doesn't, it still can work in some or even many browsers but you have no guarantee.

Comment: HTML did not leap out into the world "fully grown and armed, with a shout". It evolved over the years; things that were optional became mandatory, and the reverse. `meta` is an example of a tag that evolved quite a bit through the years. It would be cruel for browsers to suddenly reject already existing pages if 'the standard' changes.

Answer (score 3):

1. There were bugs (or simply loose parsers) in browsers.
2. People wrote code that depended on those bugs.
3. Other browsers copied those bugs so that the code from the previous step would work.
4. Go to 1.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that your pts 1 and 2 are reciprocal: people wrote rather bad HTML, browsers were adjusted to accept it, then/thus/henceforth people wrote even *worse* HTML.

Comment: @Jongware — That would fail the "Works in *my* browser, OK, I'll publish" test.